# Ploty express uneven xticks

Tags: python

I have this dataset where the dates are spread unevenly. Since the dates are spread unevenly this also creates space between the bar. So my question is, is there a way to ignore the dates in between the dataset values so the bars are placed next to each other? I'm using ploty express and this is my code:

```
ecc_duration_by_name = df_selection.groupby(by=["Date"]).mean()[["Eccentric Duration [ms] "]]
    fig_ecc_duration = px.bar(
        ecc_duration_by_name,
        x=ecc_duration_by_name.index,
        y="Eccentric Duration [ms] ",
        title="<b>Eccentric Duration</b>",
        color_discrete_sequence=["#3679ff"] * len(ecc_duration_by_name),
        template="plotly_white",
    )
    fig_ecc_duration.update_layout(
        plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        yaxis=(dict(showgrid=False)),
    )
```

The is what the bar graph currently looks like this:
[image]

But I would like to display the bars right next to each other, like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, next time, include a minimal reproducible example.
That is, an example that contains all that is needed to test your problem, including `import plotly.express as px`, and some example data `df=...`. And that on the other hand does not include what is not really needed (computation of the data with groupby...)

Here is my shot at it

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Just an example dataframe, with 5 uneven dates, and some 5 values v
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['2021-10-11', '2021-10-12', '2021-10-20', '2021-11-01', '2022-02-02']), 'v':[10,11,8,5,15]})
# Plot 'v' vs 'Date'
fig_ecc_duration = px.bar(
    df,
    x='Date',
    y="v",
    title="<b>Eccentric Duration</b>",
    color_discrete_sequence=["#3679ff"] * len(df),
    template="plotly_white",
)

fig_ecc_duration.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    yaxis=(dict(showgrid=False)),
)
fig_ecc_duration.show()
```

Indeed, dates are uneven.
[image]

There is one mecanism in plotly to deal with time series with missing dates. It is meant (see [Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#hiding-weekends-and-holidays)) to remove a few dates, not to include some dates. So we'll have to list all the dates we **don't** have data for.

By adding, just before the last `.show()` line:

```py
# Set of dates that are in the data frame
presentDates=set(df.Date)
# Set of dates that are missing (the ones in the range of df.Date, but not among the dates)
missingDates=[d for d in pd.date_range(min(df.Date), max(df.Date), freq='D') if d not in presentDates]
# Remove those dates from xaxes
fig_ecc_duration.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[dict(values=missingDates)])

# And now we can show
fig_ecc_duration.show()
```

[image]